# ArrayAdapter, Listview и темный лес

Tags: android, listview

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemList>{

private final Context context;
ArrayList<ItemList> items;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemList> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_list);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView textid;
    protected Button btn;
    protected ImageView img;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();   
}

@Override
public ItemList getItem(int i) {
    return items.get(i);   
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;                   
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View view = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list,null);
    }else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.textid = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textid);
    viewHolder.btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    viewHolder.img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    viewHolder.btn.setText(" " + items.get(position).getM_id());
    viewHolder.textid.setText(" " + items.get(position).getM_id());

    return view;
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<ItemList> current_items = new ArrayList<ItemList>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        current_items.add(new ItemList(i,0.0f));
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, current_items);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Comment: Там всё не сложно. Покажите ваш код - покажем где неправильно, коли принцип вам уже понятен. Главное постарайтесь не ВООБЩЕ весь код выложить, а тот, что непосредственно к вопросу относится.

Comment: Скинул код. При запуске список даже не показывается. Ни в каком виде.

Comment: не вижу , где у вас в адаптере , собственно , связываются данные из модели с виджетами айтема . Типа   `viewHolder.btn.setText("id "+items.get(position).getM_id());`

Comment: Добавил 

`viewHolder.btn.setText(" " + items.get(position));`
`viewHolder.textid.setText(" " + items.get(position));`

не помогло.

Comment: так вы получили только определенный позицией объект из коллекции . а сами данные из объекта кто выбирать будет ? геттеры в объекте зачем ?  `items.get(position).getM_id();`

Comment: Исправил. Проблема не решена. Активность полностью пустая...

Comment: код полностью исправьте в вопросе , что вы там делали , экстрасенсов здесь нет наверное

Comment: Прошу прощения. Секунду

Comment: смотрите внимательно [пример](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listviewselection) , что я вам давал . Так можно долго по одной строчке исправлять

Comment: @Onum, у вас в адаптере не видно метода getItemCount() (в правильности не уверен названия).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
Все заработало , спасибо огромное!!!
Нужно было переопределить методы
`public int getCount()`
`public ItemList getItem(int i) `

`public long getItemId(int i) `

Comment: @Onum, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давай те ка я попробую. Не объясняя а на примере:

```
//1 - находим ListView
        ListView lvMain = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.gvMain);   
//2 - создаем массивы данных, которые нужно передать
String[] txtForTextView;
int[] imageResourceId; // массив идентификаторов на картинки типа {R.drawable.myimage1,R.drawable.myimage2, .. }
String[] txtForButtons;
//3 - создаем адаптер и в него передаем все массивы данных в конструкторе (конструктор потом создадим такой какой нужно).
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(v.getContext(), R.layout.listItem,txtForTextView,imageResourceId,txtForButtons);

//4 - дальше все просто, устанавливаем адаптер к listView       
        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
//5 - а так вешаем обработку нажатий на элемент listView - думаю описать листенер сможешь сам.
        lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

теперь класс MyCustomAdapter:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    int mResource;  
    String[] txtForTextView;
    int[] imageResourceId;
    String[] txtForButtons;


    //в конструкторе соответственно передаем все входящие данные в поля адаптера
    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,String[] txtForTextView, int[] imageResourceId,String[] txtForButtons) {       
        this.mResource=resource;        
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.txtForTextView=txtForTextView;
        this.imageResourceId=imageResourceId;
        this.txtForButtons=txtForButtons;
    }

    // осталось только переопределить процедуру создания элемента view, по сути адаптер нужен просто чтобы создать itemView для ListView
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
        View view;  // создаем itemView из заданного layout     
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }

            //а дальше все просто устанавливаем ресурсы во view как обычно
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listImageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId[position]);

            TextView txtView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listTextView);
            txtView.setText(txtForTextView[position]);

            Button buttonView=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.listTextView);
            buttonView.setText(txtForButtons[position]);

                        return view;
    }

    // надо будет еще определить методы которые требуются для BaseAdapter, но думаю с этим справишся.

Вобщем с адаптером все просто - передаешь все нужные данные в конструктор, потом в процедуре getView прицепляешь эти данные к кнопкам, в зависимости от position
```

Comment: стоит заметить , что для обучающего примера данный код подойдет , но  в реальном приложении категорично рекомендуется использовать класс-holder , который будет хранить ссылки на элементы view / Это позволит существенно улучшить производительность и скорость прокрутки списка .

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный пример. 
Теперь многое для меня стало на свои места. 
Вот по классу Holder я по моему видел статью на хабре, там правда статья 2011 года и я не совсем был уверен что механизмы которые там описаны актуальны, по этому оставил это на потом.

Comment: @pavlofff вы когда нибудь замеряли на сколько холдер ускоряет прокртуку в реальном приложении для Андроид 4.0+ ?

Comment: нет , лично я таких измерений не проводил , однако операция получения view очень ресурсоемка , а при создании списка без холдера выполняется при создании КАЖДОГО айтема в списке столько раз , сколько у вас виджетов в айтеме (для каждого  TextView , ImageView и тд.) - это сильно расходует ресурсы устройства , поэтому придумали механизм сохранения этих view (а они в каждом айтеме одни и те же ), чтоб не получать их каждый раз заново , а использовать уже готовые и не расходовать на это ресурсы . Это очень хорошая практика в разработке вообще , а не только в конкретном данном случае со списками .

Comment: Да согласен, с холдером наверно получше. Если что вот есть реализация с холдером : http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/ вроде там понятно как холдер добавить.

Comment: @pavlofff Холдер нужен чтобы избавиться от лишних вызовов findViewById() - если вы откроете код findViewById() то заметите что он банально рекурсивно пробегает все вложенные вьюшки пока не найдет нужный ID. Для простых лаяутов в которых до десятка view он(холдер) дает ускорение порядка 1.5% ± погрешность тестирования, что визуально заметно чуть менее чем никак. UPD. Само же переиспользование convertView дает ускорение порядка 10 раз.

Comment: @anber Позволю себе не согласиться насчет десятка вью , возможно в каком то учебном примере по ListView их и десяток , в реальном приложении R.id содержит сотни записей . RecyclerView требует принудительной организации холдера , если бы его влияние было столь незначительно , его бы не использовали

Comment: @pavlofff а при чем тут R.id? И да предлагаю перейти в чат чтоб не засорять ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую подойти к вопросу с другой стороны: разберитесь что такое `LayoutInflater` - он используется в адаптере.
Если вкратце зачем нужен `inflator`: если у вас есть XML файл с разметкой - к примеру `LinearLayout` внутри у которого есть `Button`(с id button_view), `TextView`(c id text_view) и `ImageView`. Так вот, вы с помощью `inflator` можете создать `View` по этому шаблону:

```
// создать inflator
// в качестве параметра context обычно 
// передается Activity, например MainActivity.this 
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

// если ваша XML с LinearLayout, 
// кнопкой и прочим называется item.xml 
// то создадим по ее шаблону View:
View oneView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item);

// далее в этом view можно найти TextView
// с id text_view и задать ему текст:
TextView text = (TextView) oneView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
text.setText("Hello World!!!")

// далее в этом view можно найти Button
// с id button_view и задать установить ему обработчик нажатия:
Button button = (Button) oneView.findViewById(R.id.button_view);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something
    }
});
```

Далее при помощи этого же `inflator` можно создать еще один `View` по шаблону  `item.xml`, задать ему текст и обработчик нажатия на кнопку итд..

```
View secondView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item);
```

Эти View можно просто добавить в любой пустой `layout`, например `LinearLayout`:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
layout.addView(oneView);
layout.addView(secondView);
```

Рабочий пример с inflator можно глянуть тут - https://github.com/akadatsky/itemExample.git

Когда разберетесь с inflator можно переходить к ListView, там должно быть уже более понятно. 
Пример непосредственно с ListView можно глянуть тут - https://github.com/akadatsky/lisvViewSample

Comment: Скорее всего вы правы, у меня просто в голове не укладывается сама концепция этого всего и по этому одна путаница , Ваш пример очень полезный , спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Onum при личной встрече с рисованием на бумажке/доске это предельно просто объяснить, к сожалению тут формат не тот :)

Comment: к сожалению, а иногда хочется спросить у кого-то , что бы на пальцах показали) Я могу оставить вам свой скайп. Если вы не против. Обещаю не заморачивать Вас тоннами вопросов.

Answer (score 2):

> Проблема в том что понимание того что такое адаптер никак не спасает. Я не могу понять как мне создать например кучу элементов такого вида.

Видимо у вас все же неправильное понимание , что такое adapter , потому что именно он и создает "кучу элементов" на основе одного шаблона-разметки и подставляя в этот шаблон по очереди данные , которые надо отобразить в списке . С вашей стороны требуется только предоставить ему необходимые данные , остальную "кучу" он сделает сам

То есть ListView обращается к адаптеру всякий раз , когда требуется очередной айтем ( элемент списка ), а адаптер формирует этот айтем на основе общего шаблона и предоставленных ему для отображения данных , выбирая из них требуемые только для конкретной запрошенной позиции и формируя заполненный именно требуемыми в данной позиции view для отображения в очередной строке списка .

> Что бы еще в дальнейшем взаимодействовать с ними.

Для этого есть множество методов , как у класса ListView , так и у класса Adapter - перечислять их все несколько проблематично , обратитесь , к примеру , к оффициальной документации Android /
Насчет взаимодействия с какой то кнопкой внутри айтема , то тут все тоже просто , вешаете на эту кнопку слушатель , обычно в классе-holder-e и пишете код - действие по клику , имея позицию , id или еще чего нужное для различения какой именно айтем был нажат ,  которое вам предоставит адаптер с помощью своих методов

> Как мне создать, например 10 элементов такого списка

вам нужно просто скормить адаптеру данные из десяти позиций. Так как данных может быть очень много , то конкретнее ответить затруднительно . Например выборка из БД с десятью строками , массив строк из десяти ячеек и тд.

> как его научить взаимодействовать с этим ListView

нужно просто привязать адаптер к списку , методом класса ListView - setAdapter()

> к примеру класс ItemElement как элемент списка со своими данными

Для взаимодействия объектов-модели с списком вам нужно написать в модели геттеры-сеттеры для получения-изменения значений элементов из объекта, создать коллекцию этих объектов в любом подходящем хранилище , например ArrayList - он будет содержать все ваши объекты для отображения в списке .. Затем через конструктор адаптера передать эту коллекцию в адаптер , в адаптере переопределить метод getView() и заполнять виджеты шаблона-разметки данными из модели , используя геттеры для извлечения нужных значений для виджетов .

[здесь](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listviewselection) рассматривается пример ( [перевод на русский](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/) )  списка ListView с использованием объекта-модели и заодно взаимодействие с виджетом CheckBox в айтеме , что почти тоже самое , что и Button , хотя и немного сложнее , рекомендую так же прочитать всю статью целиком , ибо она одна собрала в себе практически всё о использовании ListView на практике .

Comment: Эта теория намного лучше чем на большинство сайтах, спасибо за ответы и примеры. 
Пора мне учиться осваивать всё по официальной документации.